# EventWaitHandle WaitOne error with TimeSpan for approx 1 year

Tags: c#

I'm fetching `TimeSpan` for 1 year and trying to do `WaitOne` for `EventWaitHandle`, but getting error,

How to handle this case?

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1.
>   Parameter name: timeout'

```
private static readonly EventWaitHandle eventWait = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            var span = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Math.Round((DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds, 3));

            if (eventWait.WaitOne(span))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("test");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the milliseconds at all (number too large of one year)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
Math.Round((DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds, 3) <= int.MaxValue
```

is

```cs
false
```

Regard doc your timespan is to big since int.MaxValue in maximum timespan value that EventWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan) consumes w/o exception.

You can try -1 for infinite wait.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it contained too many false pretences. You are right, the problem is that `EventWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan)` can't wait for that long.